# Which one to choose HttpRequestMessage(HttpClient) or HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am into a scenario where my code was written with HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse (System.Net). This was on.Net4.5.2.
But for platform independence reason I am migrating my code to NetStandard. For some reason, I am on NetStandard 1.6(not tried 2.0 yet).

Problem: Response with status code 403 (Forbidden).

Original code:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("url") as HttpWebRequest;
/*
. adding headers/ filling content
.
*/

var req = request as WebRequest;
try{
req.GetResponse();
}catch(WebException ex){

}
```

This code use to catch response with 403(Forbidden) status as web exception. But with this new code.

I can migrate code to NetStandard 1.6 using 2 approaches

```
Approach 1: //System.Net.Http 

var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
/*
. adding headers/ filling content/method
.
*/

var client = new HttpClient();
//client.credentials = credentials //credentials if required
try{
client.SendAsync(request).Result;
}catch(exception ex){

}
```

Here response with 403 status (forbidden) will not be an exception anymore. it's just response. So this is a new behavior for my code/ won't retro fit.

Approach 2: using System.Net.Requests - NuGet package. 4.3.0

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("url") as HttpWebRequest;
    /*
    . adding headers/ filling content
    .
    */

    var req = request as WebRequest;
    try{
    req.GetResponseAsync().Result;
    }catch(AggregateException ex){
    var webEx = ex.InnerExceptions[0] as WebException;
    //To get my previous behavior back / retrofit
    }
```

This works as my original code only thing is sync APIs are not available. I need manage with WebRequest.GetResponseAsync().Result Which throws an Aggregate exception for 403 response. little extra work to retrofit.

So now I m not able to conclude on which one to use.
Someone please help to choose either of HttpRquestMessage(HttpClient) or HttpWebRequest, and tell why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the first approach, you can make it act similar by handling the response. You could do something like:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
/*
. adding headers/ filling content/method
.
*/

var client = new HttpClient();
//client.credentials = credentials //credentials if required
try
{
    var result = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // throws if not success
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // handle exception here
}
```

This is likely as close as you will get to code acting in the same manner without having to dig through inner exceptions to determine if it was an HTTP error or not.